# How to call QMainWindow class method from within extended QListWidget class dropEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt

Here is a working piece of source code.
When you run it, simply drag and drop an item from the first listWidget to the second listWidget.

I have a print statement in the dropEvent where I'd like to call the parent QMainWindow's method named "special".

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt,QString
import sys, os

class ThumbListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    _rows_to_del=[]

    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(ThumbListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(124, 124))
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self._dropping = False

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(ThumbListWidget, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(ThumbListWidget, self).dragMoveEvent(event)

    def dropEvent(self, event):

        print "How can I call the main window class method called 'special' here?"

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), links)
        else:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            self._dropping = True
            super(ThumbListWidget, self).dropEvent(event)
            self._dropping = False

    def rowsInserted(self, parent, start, end):
        if self._dropping:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), (start, end))
        super(ThumbListWidget, self).rowsInserted(parent, start, end)

    def dataChanged(self,start,end):
        if self._dropping:
            for row in range(start.row(),end.row()+1):
                index = self.indexFromItem(self.item(row))
                shot = index.data().toString()
                #print len(self.findItems(shot,Qt.MatchExactly))
                if len(self.findItems(shot,Qt.MatchExactly))>1:
                    self._rows_to_del.append(row)

            self._rows_to_del.reverse()

            for row in self._rows_to_del:
                self.takeItem(row)

            self._rows_to_del=[]

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.listItems={}

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)

        self.listWidgetA = ThumbListWidget(self)
        for i in range(12): 
            QtGui.QListWidgetItem( 'Item '+str(i), self.listWidgetA )

        all_items =  self.listWidgetA.findItems(QString('*'), Qt.MatchWrap | Qt.MatchWildcard)
        for item in all_items:
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable )
            # item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.listWidgetA)

        self.listWidgetB = ThumbListWidget(self)

        self.listWidgetA.setAcceptDrops(False)

        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.listWidgetB)   

        self.connect(self.listWidgetA, QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), self.items_dropped)
        self.listWidgetA.currentItemChanged.connect(self.item_clicked)

        self.connect(self.listWidgetB, QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), self.items_dropped)
        self.listWidgetB.currentItemChanged.connect(self.item_clicked)

    def items_dropped(self, arg):
        print 'items_dropped', arg
        start,end = arg
        #print range(start,end+1)
        for row in range(start,end+1):
            item = self.listWidgetB.item(row)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable )
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

    def special(self):
        print "special called"

    def item_clicked(self, arg):
        print "arg=",arg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're passing the window along to the constructor of your custom widget as `self`, which becomes the parent of your custom widget.  So you should just be able to do

```
window = self.parent()
window.special()
```

You could also use the Qt event system to emit an event that your main window could connect to and call the `special` method itself.

```
class ThumbListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    my_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self.my_signal.emit()


class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.listWidgetB = ThumbListWidget(self)
        self.listWidgetB.my_signal.connect(self.special)
```

Comment: The first suggestion is the type of answer I seek, but it doesn't work because the parent is QWidget and not QMainWindow.  I realize, I could recurse the parent() values until I get to __main__, but that seems clunky.  There must be a better way.

Comment: @panofish  Yeah, the event system is usually the *right* way to do this, as it means your widget can do stuff without having to know the context of how it's being used.  If it truly is something that your widget is supposed to manage, you can pass in a callback.

There are other ways -- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#activeWindow -- but they all require you to make assumptions about the type of application your widget is being used in.

Comment: Ah.. good information Brendan.  I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know.  Thanks.